# Multiple Regression (sequential) - Meaning of variable becoming insignificant after addtition of new variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, model-comparison

I´ve got problems with interpreting my multiple regression results. In my first model I´ve included only my DV and my sex as a dummy (0=men 1= Women).

There is a significant positive relationship between sex and my DV. In my second model I added a variable and the previous relationship becomes insignificant, the new variable significant.

My substantive interest was in testing that women would be more positive on the DV because of the phenomenon captured by the variable (values) I added in model 2.

Does the drop in significance (and big reduction of b-coefficient) mean that women more positive effect on DV (in Model 1) is "explained" by the variable in Model 2? I think that women subscribe to these values more strongly and that this is responsible for their higher values on the dependent variable.

does then the partialling out of the effects of the values in model 2 (making sex insignificant) fall in line with what i expected or contradict it?

Answer (score 0):

With regression you need to think about actual causality.  It could be that there is just a very high correlation between sex and the new variable.  And, it might just be random that that variable fits a bit better and 'takes away' from sex as explanatory - even though it is not 'real'.

Suppose, for instance, that hair length is your new variable.  On average women probably have longer hair than men.  But suppose you are trying to determine hearing loss rates.  Women may, indeed, be more susceptible to hearing loss with age (I don't know, but let's suppose so), but you might pick up in hair length a lot of rock musicians who are men (depending on where you got your data) who have hearing loss from years of exposure to loud sounds.

That doesn't say anyhting about the link to sex.  It says everything about your sample.

Comment: Some good points but I don't think it answers the OPs somewhat unclear question.